# How does Yubo previously known as Yello remember users after reinstall?

Tags: ios, iphone, applescript, ios11, iphone-6

Okay, I have asked Reddit 3x and Apple once and no one could answer this so I am coming to you guys. Please be the ones to answer this validly. Okay, details. Yubo remembers my phone after reinstall and I do not know how. I have tried the following:

- Changed my IP Address using a VPN
- Change my IDFA through reset identifier which I now know is pointless as since I had “limit ad tracking” on the output would have been an output value of numerous 0’s (though this some how got me unbanned from the “Instagram” app, idk how tho)
- Changed my IDFV by...well reinstalling the app (Yubo is there only app so don’t ask about other apps from the vendor)
- Change my iPhones name multiple times
- Prevented the app from being backed up on Icloud then reinstalling
- I also logged out of the Icloud prior to using the app for the first time after reinstall

And that’s about it. I am aware the app may recognize: my phone, ios version and hardware. However, none of that is exclusive to my phone. I have read people having the exact same model and phone so i doubt Yubo is remembering me through that. I have never met an app so smart before, but I know some of you have probably been screaming this entire time one thing I have missed so please tell me what i missed and a way to change it without resetting my phone.

My device: Iphone6s and IOS 11

Comment: They might be using the iCloud Keychain to save your identity

Comment: How is that possible? Isn’t the keychain just for passwords? Also how would I reset that?

Comment: The keychain is most often used to save things like passwords, but you could theoretically save any piece of information there. I know you can disable iCloud Keychain syncing in your iCloud settings. I'm not sure if that'd actually purge existing keys that have already been saved to the device at the time you disable it. I think you can see everything saved to your iCloud Keychain in the Keychain app on your Mac.

Comment: So if I didn’t have a mac, is there any other way i would be able to view everything saved to my keychain? And if deleting keychains doesn’t remove existing ones, what would?

Comment: They are probably using the local device keychain. The only way to remove it is to erase your phone.  They can also use the DeviceCheck framework. There is no way to clear that since the value is kept on their servers and linked to your device

Comment: I cleared my device keychain completely both from Icloud and my phone, you’re saying it’s still possible to be there? And would erasing my phone frequently while keeping a backup be a good idea? As for DeviceCheck I have never heard of that before so thank you for that.

Comment: Are you sure Yubo is not reading your phone number or asking email address ?